# Permission denied to drop objects

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

Running `drop owned by <username>;` gives me `ERROR:  permission denied to drop objects`. I can login/create/insert/update/alter etc fine.

Created the db and role like so:

1. `sudo psql -U postgres`
2. `CREATE USER <username> WITH PASSWORD '<password>';`
3. `CREATE DATABASE <dbname> OWNER <username> ;`

Looking up the problem, these are some of the things I ran that did not solve the issue:

- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <username>;`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <username>;`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <dbname> to <username>;`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <username>;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the owner, or a superuser, can drop an object. There is no privilege which allows dropping of an object, hence this is not something which can be granted to others.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be universally correct. On a RDS PostgreSQL instance, you'll get this error even as the owner.

Comment: RDS is not PostgreSQL, even though Amazon makes you believe this. It's their own fork with special handling for details.

Comment: Then how to drop the user or role from RDS Aurora Postgres cluster?